Casella/Berger: "Under the random sampling model each X_i is an obs on the same var and each X_i has a marg dist given by f(x)."
On page 169, Casella and Berger give the following definition:

Definition 5.1.1 The random variables $X_1, ..., X_n$ are called a random sample of size n from the population $f(x)$ if $X_1,..., X_n$ are mutually independent random variables and the
marginal pdf or pmf of each $X_i$ is the same function $f(x)$.

After this definition, they include the following comment:

The random sampling model describes a type of experimental situation in which the variable of interest has a probability distribution described by $f(x)$. If only one observation $X$ is made on this variable, then the probabilities regarding $X$ can be calculated using $f(x)$. In most experiments there are $n>1$ (a fixed, positive integer) repeated observations made on the variable, the first observation is $X_1$, the second is $X_2$, and so on. Under the random sampling model each $X_i$ is an observation on the same variable and each $X_i$ has a marginal distribution given by $f(x)$. Furthermore, the observations are taken in such a way that the value of one observation has no effect on or relationship with any of the other observations; that is, $X_1, ..., X_n$ are mutually independent.


I found several parts of the above comment to be extremely confusing. More specifically:

The random sampling model describes a type of experimental situation in which the variable of interest has a probability distribution described by $f(x)$.

What is the "variable of interest"? I am guessing it is $X$? Why not give it a name?


If only one observation $X$ is made on this variable, then probabilities regarding $X$ can be calculated using $f(x)$.

This sentence does not make sense. In the first part of the sentence, $X$ is said to be an observation (say, $0.8$, for example). But in the second part of the sentence, there is disussion about a "probability regarding $X$". If $X = 0.8$, then there is no "probability" to talk about--$X$ is $0.8$, and will still be $0.8$ tomorrow, next year and 100 years from now.


Under the random sampling model each $X_i$ is an observation on the same variable and each $X_i$ has a marginal distribution given by $f(x)$.

Similar to statement #2, this statement also makes no sense. If $X_1 = 0.5, X_2 = 0.7, X_3 = -100$, then how can one talk about a "marginal distribution" for the real numbers $0.5, 0.7, -100$? To the best of my understanding, the statement "The marginal distribution of $0.5$" is nonsensical.




This textbook seems to be very popular in graduate programs, and I am a mere beginner in statistics, so I am obviously missing something. Thank you in advance for any guidance and help.

This an issue with describing a "random variable" with words that make sense to learners.  Saying something like "a measurable function from a sample space to a measurable space" would probably not help.  There is a need to consider the distinction between a random variable and an observation (some people use $X_i$ and $x_i$ for this) and to cover the question of several observations: are those multiple observations of the same random variable or are they individual observations of different random variables which have the same distribution?

Let this confusion not withhold you from doing some exercises that are linked with this stuff. That might be revealing for you.

It is understandable that you are confused. The Casella Berger book is a useful statistics overview book, but it is not written in a way that is intended for mathematicians. Its popularity lie mainly in the non-mathematical students of statistics. In particular, as you have pointed out, it does not state the framework of statistical decision theory in an understandable manner.
In brief, when you receive data $X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_n = x_n$, what you do in practice is to give the data a model. That is, for instance if we are in frequentist approach, you assume the data comes from a distribution (e.g. normal with a true mean and variance) in a family of distributions (e.g. normal with some mean and variance) you specify. Then, you carry out any inference procedure to say give a confidence interval of where that true parameter lies. Therefore, in more mathematical terms :
A population is a family of probability measures, which let us denote by $\mathcal{P}$. In most cases, you decide $\mathcal{P}$. A sample of $n$ (real) observations $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ is a collection of $n$ independent identically distributed random variables defined on some probability space that has the common law $P \in \mathcal{P}$. If $\lambda$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure and (say the Lebesgue measure) and $P << \lambda$ for all $P \in \mathcal{P}$, then the probability density functions of measures in $P$ will completely determine its elements. It is frequent that $\mathcal{P}$ is parametrized. That is, $\mathcal{P} = \{P_{\theta}\}_{\theta \in \Theta}$, in which case $\theta$ will usually be the parameter of interest.
For more details, search "statistical decision theory" and you will find math textbooks explaining these concepts. I personally recommend Jun Shao's "Mathematical Statistics". There are quite a few written by others as well.

Thank you very much for taking the time to respond. Your response is enlightening. Per your suggestion, I have ordered the textbook by Prof. Shao. To be honest, I was not able to follow the comments in the 3rd paragraph of your answer, but hopefully the book by Prof. Shao will assist me in this endeavor. Thank you again for your response.

I tried to cover half of the chapter 2 in Shao's book in one paragraph. More details are definitely needed. Good luck reading the book!
